# Function has vertical tangent or vertical cusp?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine whether or not the graph of the function has a vertical tangent or vertical cusp at the indicated point c.

$f(x) = (x+2)^7/3$
$c=-2$

I took the first derivative and chain rule and
that got me.

$ f'(x) = 7/3(x+2)^4/3*1$

Then I plugged in c

$f'(-2) = 7/3(-2+2)^4/3 = 0$

Then I put that into a line graph.

**___0______**

Then I got

$f(-1) =1^7/3$

$f(1) = 2^7/3$

Thus this is a vertical cusp. Is this right or wrong?

Comment: Your $ \ f(x) \ $ is a polynomial function: since the derivative function of a polynomial function is _always_ defined, it does not have vertical tangents or cusps.

Comment: You have shown that $f(x)$ has an extreme point at $c = -2$.

Comment: A vertical tangent or cusp would appear where the slope diverges. You have shown that the slope at that point remains finite. Thus there is no vertical tangent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of a vertical cusp is that the one-sided limits of the derivative approach opposite $ \pm \infty $: positive infinity on one side and negative infinity on the other side. A vertical tangent has the one-sided limits of the derivative equal to the same sign of infinity. As a result, the derivative at the relevant point is undefined in both the cusp and the vertical tangent.

You have a case where the derivative exists, as you showed in your question. Therefore, it is neither a cusp nor a vertical tangent.

Comment: Is there a way to show your answer algebraically perhaps?

Comment: As @RecklessReckoner wrote, the given function is a polynomial, and no polynomial has a cusp or a vertical tangent. This is clear since polynomials have derivatives everywhere, which excludes cusps and vertical tangents. That is an algebraic statement, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

At $x=2$, the tangent line is horizontal, since the derivative at that point is zero.

A vertical tangent means that the derivative at that point approches infinity, since the slope is infinitely large.